# Retorno de resultados duplicados SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte SQL

```
SELECT 
    `inte`.`int_nome`, 
    `age`.*, 
    `con_at`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_atendeu, 
    `con_ag`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_agendou 
FROM (`agendamentos` as age) 
    JOIN `interessados` as inte ON `inte`.`int_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_interessado` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_at ON `con_at`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_atendido` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_ag ON `con_ag`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado` 
WHERE `inte`.`int_nome` LIKE '%baill%' 
GROUP BY `age`.`age_cod`
```

Porém, na hora de listar, ele busca todos os registros e imprime **errado**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo que eu execute a query sugerida pelo nosso amigo Victor:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `inte`.`int_nome`, 
    `age`.*, 
    `con_at`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_atendeu, 
    `con_ag`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_agendou 
FROM (`agendamentos` as age) 
    JOIN `interessados` as inte ON `inte`.`int_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_interessado` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_at ON `con_at`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_atendido` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_ag ON `con_ag`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado` 
WHERE `inte`.`int_nome` LIKE '%baill%' 
GROUP BY `age`.`age_cod`
```

O que estou errando na consulta?

Comment: O nosso querido `SELECT DISTINCT` não resolveria o problema? E a outra questão é: as outras tabelas não tem mais entradas do mesmo USER [Como mostra o age_cod, 1 e 3] ?

Comment: Onde estão os duplicados? São diferentes todos os resultados...

Comment: Olhando para o `age_cod` da sua imagem, temos 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 e 8. Qual deles é duplicado e porque?

Comment: Eu continuo sem perceber André. Qual é o problema afinal?

Comment: Você faz uma pesquisa por todos os registos que contenham "Baill", o resultado parece ser o esperado. O que é que você pretende obter?

Comment: @JorgeB. o problema é que na hora de exibir, ele lista todos os registros, trocando apenas o nome, porque a ideia é fazer uma pesquisa pelo nome, e retornar apenas o resultado daquele nome em questão, mas o nome está em outra tabela.

Comment: @AndréBaill mas aqueles registos não são todos daquele usuário? É que parece que são.

Comment: O que você está tentando obter é uma lista de agendamentos, uma lista de interessados, uma lista de consultoras ou uma lista de que afinal? O que é que você chama de duplicado e o que é que você não chama de duplicado?

Comment: A lista que eu preciso é a lista de agendamentos daquele nome em questão

Comment: Mas no meu where, adicionei: WHERE `inte`.`int_nome` LIKE '%baill%' AND `age`.`age_cod_interessado` = `inte`.`int_cod` parece que resolveu

Comment: O que faço? Podes fechar o tópico? Aparentemente resolveu a questão, usando o int.int_cod

Comment: Poste uma resposta com a solução.

Answer (score 1):

É só colocar um `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `inte`.`int_nome`, 
    `age`.*, 
    `con_at`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_atendeu, 
    `con_ag`.`con_nome` as consultora_que_agendou 
FROM (`agendamentos` as age) 
    JOIN `interessados` as inte ON `inte`.`int_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_interessado` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_at ON `con_at`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_atendido` 
    JOIN `consultoras` as con_ag ON `con_ag`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado` 
WHERE `inte`.`int_nome` LIKE '%baill%' 
GROUP BY `age`.`age_cod`
```

Comment: Mas onde estão os duplicados?

Comment: As vezes dá-me ideia que as pessoas nem leem as perguntas ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Li sim a pergunta. Ele quer eliminar os registros duplicados. Agora, se a definição de "duplicado" dele não for a que todos os outros esperam, aí paciência...

Comment: mas os resultados que ele mostra não são duplicados, só isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, os resultados que ele deu como exemplo não são duplicados, mas se por ventura pudessem ser, basta colocar o `distinct` na query. Por outro lado, todo esse debate, me faz pensar se o correto não seria simplesmente votar para fechar essa pergunta como "*não está claro o que você está perguntando*".

Comment: Realmente, o `DISTINCT` resolveria o problema de duplicações, porém os resultados que estão retornando são diferentes, pois o 'age_cod' é diferente nos resultados.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se calhar era mesmo isso. Até já fiz o obséquio :)

Comment: @CleidimarViana Mas, você sabe se o `age_cod` deve ou não ser levado em conta para considerar se dois dados registros devem ser considerados duplicados ou não? Acho que só o OP poderia dizer isso. No entanto, aquele `GROUP BY` me sugere que deve ser levado em conta sim, e portanto não seria esse campo o problema.

Comment: Modifiquei a minha questão, deixar mais clara.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não é só esse campo que difere, a data não é a mesma. De qualquer forma, esta resposta nunca seria válida com aqueles resultados da pergunta. Um `DISTINCT` iria dar os mesmos resultados.

Comment: @jorgeB, deu sim os mesmos results.

Comment: Acho que se eu agrupar por nome, talvez resolveria, mas penso que não seria a maneira correta de retornar o resultado.

Comment: @AndréBaill mas ao fazeres isso ias deturpar os resultados, afinal não queres pesquisar todos os agendamentos do 'baill'?